# Chrome extension simple audio

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I would like to play a simple "alarm" in chrome extension but i have and error in console: "`GET chrome-extension://invalid/ net::ERR_FAILED`   `chrome-extension://invalid/:1`"
My simple code is:

```
var asdasd = '<span id="audio"></span>';
$('body').append(asdasd);
var srcaudio = chrome.extension.getURL('alert2.mp3'); 
$('#audio').html('<audio autoplay><source src="'+srcaudio+'"></audio>');
```

And my manifest is:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "test",
  "description": "test",
  "version": "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["jquery.js","myscript.js"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: To load extension resources on a web page you need to declare them in [web_accessible_resources](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/web_accessible_resources).

Comment: If you are calling it from the extension itself you can simply do `new Audio("alert2.mp3").play();`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i tried to do this in my own extension.

As wOxxOm said, you probably need `web_asseible_resources`. For me the css/js/fonts are in the assets package. I dunno where you placed it.

```
"web_accessible_resources": [
    "assets/css/*",
    "assets/js/*",
    "assets/fonts/*"
  ]
```

Secondly, `extension.getUrl()` is deprecated, so use `runtime.getUrl()` instead, as for the url try to use `"./alert2.mp3"` or `"~/alert2.mp3"` if the direct path isn't working